# How to get library version update notification while using separate dependency gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I have created a separated "dependencies.gradle" file where to locate all project's dependencies, but now Android Studio doesn't give me any information about new libraries version. How can I achieve both results, one single file for managing all project's dependencies and continuous to get automatic information about new library version?

[This is app module gradle file and dependency at line 71 is not updated but I don't have any information how it's visible for lines 74 and 75](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pjQm.png)

This is my dependencies.gralde file

```
   ext {

    // Android
    minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    //Dependency versions
    kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    andorix_core_ktx_version = '1.2.0-alpha02'
    rx_kotlin_version = '2.2.0'
    rx_android_version = '2.1.1'
    lifecycle_version = '2.2.0-alpha02'
    nav_version = '2.1.0-alpha06'
    firebase_analytics_version = '17.0.0'
    firebase_messaging_version = '19.0.1'
    firebase_core_version = '17.0.0'
    firabase_crashlytics_version = '2.10.1'
    gson_version = '2.8.5'
    room_version = '2.1.0'
    junit_version = '4.12'
    dagger_version = '2.14.1'

    //Kotlin
    kotlinJDK8 = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    andoridxCoreKtx = "androidx.core:core-ktx:$andorix_core_ktx_version"

    //RxKotlin dependency
    rxKotlin = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rx_kotlin_version"
    rxAndroid = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rx_android_version"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    lifecycleExtension = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    lifecycleCompiler = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    //Navigation
    navigationFragment = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    navigationUI = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    //Firebase dependency
    firebaseAnalytics = "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$firebase_analytics_version"
    firebaseMessaging = "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_messaging_version"
    firebaseCore = "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_core_version"
    firebaseCrashlytics = "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$firabase_crashlytics_version"

    //Gson dependency
    gson = "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"

    //Room dependency
    roomRuntime = "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    roomCompiler = "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    roomRxJava2 = "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    //Dagger2
    dagger = "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    daggerAndroid = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    daggerAndroidSupport = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    daggerAndroidProcessor = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"

    // Testing
    junit = "junit:junit:$junit_version"
    androidTestRunner = 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    roomTest = "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"


}
```

Have anyone else had the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

just move versions into the **project level build.gradle** file under the `ext` scope like below

```
ext {

    support_version = '1.0.0-rc02'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.1.14'
    rxKotlinVersion = '2.2.0'
    timberVersion = '4.7.0'
}
```

and then use this version in your app/build.gradle like below

```
"androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$support_version"
```

you'll be noticed about new version

[image]

Comment: @Lupinixio, if this answer is correct please approve it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, usually I make as you said and it works, but now I was trying to move all out of that file.
Moving these variables out of the project level build.gradle file, the only way to automatically check libraries update is to go inside the Project Structure panel.